# Architecture/Platform independent installer for deploying Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, deployment

I have developed a Qt application and now want to deploy my application. I know Qt (being platform independent), needs to be compile for every platform and architecture. So, I am planning to cross-compile it for every architecture and platform and get the executables and dll files (or shared object in Linux).

I am looking for a installer which can decide on run-time the architecture and platform of the system in which it is running and copy the right binary to the desired location in that system. I know I need to provide every possible dll file and executable file but I don't want to provide a different installer for every architecture and platform that we are going to support. I don't want to distribute different installer for different architecture (e.g. windows/i3, windows/i5 etc) under different directories.

So, I am looking for free open-source installer which doesn't require to be compiled for every possible architecture and platform (may be one written in java?).

Can somebody help me in deciding which architecture should we cross-compile for? 
A binary compiled for i3 Intel core will be able to run on i5 and i7 (because of backward compatibility?)?

Any suggestion on deployment of Qt application will be appreciated.

**Note:** I have tried [installJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/) and it doesn't seem to be working on windows.

Comment: Maybe this: http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ ?

Comment: @vahancho but i need to compile it for every possible architecture and platform